# Is it possible to make a single mysql-connection page

Tags: php, mysql, connection

I want to create a single connection page that i could configure this page once each time and all of the pages that needs connection to mysql uses this page? like wordpress that it has just one configuration page.
if yes how can i do that ?

Comment: By implementing the connection exactly how you describe it, be it as a function or a class in a separate file and then including that file into all parts of your application that require a db connection.

Comment: I want to do some how they way that you described. I think that peyhab solution will work.

Comment: It definitely works :-) It is the standard in all db based php implementations.

Comment: Thank you, I've tried it and it worked.

Comment: That is good news! Have fun while programming!

Comment: You shouldn't use peyhab's answer as mysql_ is deprecated since PHP5.5. Better use mysqli or pdo for a new application. It's faster and more secure!

Comment: Your right, and i've used mysqli method not the excat peyhab method, thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<php 

$connection = new mysqli ('SERVER','DB_USERNAME','DB_PASS','DB');
$connection -> set_charset('UTF-8');
if ($connection->connect_errno) 
{
printf ('Connect failed: %s\n', $connection->connect_error);
exit();
}
```

That's all you need in your connection.php. You can include it with

```
include('connection.php');
```

You can find many tutorials for mysqli!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make a connetion.php and in that page put your connection functions:

```
$connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD);
if (!$connection) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
}

$db_select = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$connection);
if (!$db_select) {
    die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
}
//and any other config
```

then you can easily do this in anypage you want:

```
require_once("connection.php")
```

or

```
include("connection.php");
```

Comment: You shouldn't use peyhab's answer as mysql_ is deprecated since PHP5.5. Better use mysqli or pdo for a new application. It's faster and more secure!

Comment: i just explain briefly what he should do NOT the function he can use! My answer is not a function-suggestion. It's FORMAT-SUGGESTION.

Comment: Thank you guys and i know that peyhab wanted to show me how it's possible, I've used mysqli method. I accepted michael answer because it uses new method and it's updated for the viewers.